# How do I update each element of a map with a N1QL query?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a document which looks like:

```
  "associations": {
    "MANUFACTURER": [
      "137205:24",
      "137192:24",
      "137299:24",
      "137417:24",
      "137196:24",
      "137318:24",
      "137436:24",
      "137134:24",
    ]
}
```

I want to iterate all the elements in `MANUFACTURER` and concat `VBU:` to all the beginning of all the elements in that list.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ARRAY construct

```
ARRAY "VBU:"|| v FOR v IN associations.MANUFACTURER END

UPDATE mybucket AS b
SET b.associations.MANUFACTURER = ARRAY "VBU:"|| v FOR v IN b.associations.MANUFACTURER END
WHERE ...;
```